# Why does GreaterThan with pattern test not work

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm stuck in a seemingly easy question, but I can't figure out why the `GreaterThan` function and the pattern test do not work. I have tried to debug it for a while, but I can't understand why.

```
f[a_?GreaterThan[0]] := "!"

f[6] (*return f[6] itself*)
```

Comment: perhaps you could try `f[a_?(#>0&)]:="!"`; also check [`Greater`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Greater.html) and [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) (hint: whatever follows the `?` must return a boolean value)

Comment: Triple click on `GreaterThan`. Then the lack of a parenthesis is revealed. I.e. `f[a_?(GreaterThan[0])] := "!"`

Comment: `?` is an incredibly high precedence operator (even more so that `[...]`. It binds the `GreaterThan` instead of `GreaterThan[0]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a problem with the precedence of operators. You need a set of parentheses to specify that the `[0]` part is to apply to `GreaterThan` instead of to the whole `PatternTest` expression:

```
Clear[f]
f[a_?(GreaterThan[0])] := "!"
f[6] (* ! *)
```

You can see the difference in `FullForm`:

```
FullForm[a_?GreaterThan[0]]                         (* no parentheses   *)
FullForm[a_?(GreaterThan[0])]                       (* with parentheses *)
```

returns:

```
PatternTest[Pattern[a, Blank[]], GreaterThan][0]    (* no parentheses   *)
PatternTest[Pattern[a, Blank[]], GreaterThan[0]]    (* with parentheses *)
```

`?` has very high precedence, in particular higher than `[]` (see this [Operator precedence table](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html#17226802))
.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, why is the possible reason that WRI decide to give `?` a rather high precedence?

Comment: @Eric Glad it helps. Also, I don't know enough about programming language design to answer that.